Comparing sample means to standard measurements
I am trying to best address how to determine if a sample measurement is statistically different than a standard.
If I measure any variable (lets say mass) for a sample 1000 times to determine an arithmetic mean and standard deviation, while at the same time I measure 10 different aliquots of a standard each 1000 times. Let's stipulate the data has a Gaussian distribution, how can I best characterize both the standard population and sample population of measurements and determine if the means of each are statistically different.
Can I collate all my measurements of the standard (i.e. 10,000 measurements) or would it be best to treat it as a population (n=10, where each mass is equal to the mean of the 1000 measurements taken for that aliquot).
After this can I simply run a Welch t-test or Bayes factor t-test to determine the statistical significance of the difference of means?

Just collect your data and run a t-test? Where is the issue? In the different number of samples per group?
